# Automatically adds check on hide title and add paragraph when adding text

Tags: visual-editor

It most certainty wasn't like that before. I don't know what happened but now when I try to add an enhaced text, everytime when I update the page, the boxes of hide title, add automatically paragraphs are cheked. Anyone who know why this keep happening ?